# CSS position sticky with two grid colums to bottom

Tags: css, css-grid, sticky

I want to have two columns (divs) where sometimes the right one has more content, sometimes the left one.

I would like the content in these columns to have a sticky position, but in such a way that when scrolling, the content in both columns moves down from the beginning. When the content in one of these columns "finishes", it gets stuck to the bottom of the page and "waits" until the content of the second colum ends.

If the position is set to `top:0` the content of the short column "stops" during scrolling and only starts moving downwards when it reaches the bottom of the longer column.

If the position is set to `bottom:0` it's doing nothing.

Here is codepan: https://codepen.io/jacek360/pen/MWojRJZ

I have tried many things but have not achieved the desired effect. Either nothing happens, or the lower div "blocks" before its bottom meets the bottom of the higher div.

Answer (score 0):

When width is 200px item stretches, so it would scroll not simultaneously. In this code, the objects must be the same height. Also `position:sticky; top:0px;` makes it sticky to the top not bottom. You need to use `position:absolute; bottom:0px;`. I'm not sure what exactly what you expect.

**EDIT:** if you want them to it was not movable when you srcolling just do `.column { position:relative; top:0px; }`

Comment: It's only as an example. The whole problem is that the columns will not be of equal height. I want them to start scrolling at the same time, but when the shorter one finishes it should stick to the bottom of the screen and "wait" there until the longer column finishes.

Comment: If i add ```position:relative; top:0px;``` it will scroll simultaneously, but the shorter one won't stick to the bottom of the screen after it runs out of content.

Comment: You made grid system, so they will be equal, that's how it works.

Comment: No, they are not equal, ```align-self: start;``` make them not equal.

Comment: Namely, position:relative; work at all, if you want it to stick bottom just use .column {
  position:relative;
  align-self:end;
}

Comment: I asked this question much more clearly  here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69072777/two-columns-scrolling-bahevior-with-position-sticky